# Error with after_destroy_commit using broadcast_replace_later_to with Turbo Streams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo, turbo-rails

iv been tryna implement turbo streams with friend request system and i have the following code in place:

```rb
 # models/friend_request.rb
  after_create_commit do 
    broadcast_friend_request_form_replace
  end
  
  after_destroy_commit do 
    broadcast_friend_request_form_replace
  end
 
  private
 
  def broadcast_friend_request_form_replace
    # Sends a replace broadcast to the Sender's stream, targeting the Receiver's turbo frame to perform the form changes.
    broadcast_replace_later_to [self.sender.id, self.receiver.id], target: dom_id(self.receiver), partial: "users/friend_request_form", 
      locals: { logged_in_user: self.sender, user: self.receiver, friend_request: self }
 
    # Sends a replace broadcast to the Receiver's stream, targeting the Sender's turbo frame to perform the form changes.
    broadcast_replace_later_to [self.receiver.id, self.sender.id], target: dom_id(self.sender), partial: "users/friend_request_form", 
      locals: { logged_in_user: self.receiver, user: self.sender, friend_request: self }
  end
```

The feature works with `after_create_commit` callback, however im having this error when trying to do it for the `after_destroy_commit` callback: `Discarded Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob due to a ActiveJob::DeserializationError`.

To my understanding, the error maybe related to the fact that, since im using `broadcast_replace_later_to` instead of `broadcast_replace_to`, it enqueues a background job to be done at a later time and when that happens the `object (self)` no longer exists and therefore I'm receiving the `DeserializationError error`.

I have tried using `broadcast_replace_to` instead but that makes it synchronous and what happens is that only the first callback executed after a page refresh/reload will work, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, the reason is indeed that the object no longer exists. You can do it however. Just create the job directly like this:

```
after_destroy_commit do
  Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob.perform_later(stream, action:, target:, **rendering)
end
```

See https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/turbo-rails/0.5.2/Turbo/Streams/ActionBroadcastJob#perform-instance_method